# EJS file not executing external js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have been attempting to call a function from an external js file in EJS. The EJS file contains the source code for the js file and it should be connected. However, when I try to run the function on a button click, nothing happens. I was wondering if there was some initializing that I had to do other than source code?

I've looked at all stack overflows relating to this issue. I have also looked through the syntax to make sure everything is correct.

```
function register() {
     console.log("Done");
     alert("Return back to login and enter your username and password");
};
```

```html
<a id="returnLogin" href="http://localhost:3001/login"
       class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--black mdl-color-text--white"
       onclick="register()">Register</a>
```

This should cause a popup alert to appear when the button is pressed.

Comment: Try the below,
1. External Js file is correctly mapped (check the path)
2. Clear the temporary internet files and try
3. instead of calling the function in onclick, replace the function call with some test alert inside html and see whether the alert is called. if not then something wrong in html formatting

Comment: You need to research more about how to use EJS and understand client-side architecture. In the meantime, I haven't found a place to share `href` and `onclick` features together. https://ejs.co/

Comment: @Sunil I have already tried all three of the things you mentioned. The file path is correct, I have cleared the internet files, and when I code the function in the EJS file it works as intended.

Comment: @mohammadjavadahmadi Would I need to have something in my app.js other than: app.use('/', require('./app/controllers/register'));
app.use('/register', require('./app/controllers/register')); and the other basic configs?